# Load Text Files and store it in Dataframe using Pyspark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-pig, spark-shell

I am migrating pig script to pyspark and I am new to Pyspark so I am stuck at data loading.

My **pig script** looks like:

Bag1 = LOAD '/refined/em/em_results/202112/' USING PigStorage('\u1') AS
(PAYER_SHORT: chararray
,SUPER_PAYER_SHORT: chararray
,PAID: double
,AMOUNT: double
);

I want something similar to this in Pyspark.

Currently I have tried this in **Pyspark**:
df = spark.read.format("csv").load("/refined/em/em_results/202112/*")

I am able to read the text file with this but values are coming in single column instead of separated in different columns. Please find below some sample values:

|_c0

|AZZCMMETAL2021/1211FGPP7491764     |

|AZZCMMETAL2021/1221HEMP7760484     |

Output should look like this:

_c0   _c1   _c2     _c3_c4 _c5 _c6 _c7

AZZCM METAL 2021/12 11 FGP P 7 491764

AZZCM METAL 2021/12 11 HEM P 7 760484

Any clue how to achieve this? Thanks!!

Comment: can you please share a sample of the CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

Generaly spark would try to take (,)[comma] as a separator value in you case you have to provide space as your separator.

```
df = spark.read.csv(file_path, sep =' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

This resolves the issue. Instead of `"\\u1"`, I used `"\u0001"`. Please find below the answer.

```py
df = spark.read.option("sep","\u0001").csv("/refined/em/em_results/202112/*")
```